# Integration à la Mirzakhani

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, integration, teichmuller-theory, weil-petersson-metric

Let $$
\gamma = \sum_i c_i \gamma_i
$$
be a multi-curve on a hyperbolic surface $S$. For any $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ one can define $$
f_\gamma (X) = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Mod} . \gamma} f(l_\alpha (X))
$$
as a function $f_\gamma: \mathcal{M}_{g,n} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ is the moduli space of the surface and $\mathrm{Mod}$ the mapping class group.

In one of her famous [article](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Emlyubich/Archive/Geometry/Teichmuller%20Space/Mirz3.pdf) she gave, in section 8, a formula for integrating such function against the Weil-Peterson volume, that is
$$
\int\limits_{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}} f_\gamma(X) d \mu_{WP}= \frac{2^{-M(\gamma)}}{|\mathrm{Sym}(\gamma)|} \int\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^k} f(|x|)V_{g,n}(\gamma,x)x dx
$$
Where $V_{g,n}(\gamma,.)$ is a multi variable polynomial and $M(\gamma)$ and $|\mathrm{Sym}(\gamma)|$ are correcting term for the symmetry in the problem.

---

Now I would like to integrate a function of the form $$
g_\gamma(X)= g\left(\sum_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Mod}. \gamma} f\big(l_\alpha (X)\big)\right)=g\circ f_\gamma(X)
$$
for a function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. The main difficulty is that we cannot work in the cover space $\mathcal{T}_{g,n} / \cap \mathrm{Stab}(\gamma_i)$ as she did.

Is there an other way to do it?